# Getting rows with max(date) across a virtual group of rows

Tags: sql, oracle, greatest-n-per-group

Assume I have table with this Data:

```
System  CompDate  Type
A1      Jan-1     T1
A1      Jan-2     T2 
A1      Jan-3     T3
A2      Jan-4     T2
B1      Feb-1     T1
B2      Feb-2     T1
B2      Feb-3     T2
```

I want the max date, by Type , not for each system but for each group of systems.
All A's are to be treated as one group, I want to treat all A's as if they were A1 and B's as one group, B1.

So my result would be:

```
 A1    Jan-1  T1
 A1    Jan-4  T2
 A1    Jan-3  T3
 B1    Feb-2  T1
 B1    Feb-3  T2
```

I know I can do max date by system:

```
 SELECT System, CompDate,Type
 FROM TableName T1
 WHERE  CompDate = (SELECT max(compdate) from tablename T2  
                    WHERE T2.type=T1.type
                    AND T2.System=T1.System )
```

But how do I do the grouping of all As and Bs? There is no known pattern in the values of As, so it could also be that I have systems= M, N, P and I need to treat that set as one group, maybe with header M.  There is no table that already defines the 'group' of system codes. I just know the grouping, external to the Database.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
select min(system), max(compdate), type
from t
group by (case when system in ('A1', 'A2') then 'A'
               when system in ('B1', 'B2') then 'B'
               else system
          end), type;
```

Or, you could phrase this as:

```
select (case when system in ('A1', 'A2') then 'A'
             when system in ('B1', 'B2') then 'B'
             else system
        end),
       max(compdate), type
from t
group by (case when system in ('A1', 'A2') then 'A'
               when system in ('B1', 'B2') then 'B'
               else system
          end), type;
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your system field's value has 2 characters:

```
SELECT system,
       compdate,
       type
  FROM (SELECT LEFT(system, 1) + '1' system,
               compdate,
               type,
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY LEFT(system, 1) + '1', type ORDER BY compdate DESC) rownum
          FROM tablename --your table
       ) a
 WHERE rownum = 1
```

Result

```
system  compdate    type
A1      2017-01-01  T1
A1      2017-01-04  T2
A1      2017-01-03  T3
B1      2017-02-02  T1
B1      2017-02-03  T2
```

Comment: There is no common prefix on system name.  I will test Gordon's approach